# how to supply data to a class extending DataTableSource

Tags: dart, flutter

To display data on flutter using PaginatedDataTable

I have to supply a source which is a class extending from DataTableSource 
but i can't manage to supply any data on the class which extending the DataTableSource as when i try to it through error

**"only static members can be accessed in initializers flutter"**

so how can i supply the initial data fro the DataTableSource from outside?

```
class TransactionAcrossMonthsItem {
  final String transactionName;
  final int monthOf1;
  final int monthOf2;
  final int monthOf3;
  final int monthOf4;
  final int monthOf5;
  final int monthOf6;
  final int monthOf7;
  final int monthOf8;
  final int monthOf9;
  final int monthOf10;
  final int monthOf11;
  final int monthOf12;
  final int totalCount;
  final double percent;
  bool selected = false;
  TransactionAcrossMonthsItem(
      this.transactionName,
      this.monthOf1,
      this.monthOf2,
      this.monthOf3,
      this.monthOf4,
      this.monthOf5,
      this.monthOf6,
      this.monthOf7,
      this.monthOf8,
      this.monthOf9,
      this.monthOf10,
      this.monthOf11,
      this.monthOf12,
      this.totalCount,
      this.percent);
}

class TransactionsAcrossDataSource extends DataTableSource {
  final List<TransactionAcrossMonthsItem> _data;

  int _selectedCount = 0;

  TransactionsAcrossDataSource(this._data);
...........
}




class DetailedReportPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int yearOf;
  DetailedReportPage({this.yearOf});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _DetailedReportPageState();
  }
}

class _DetailedReportPageState extends State<DetailedReportPage> {
  int _rowsPerPage = PaginatedDataTable.defaultRowsPerPage;
  int _sortColumnIndex;
  bool _sortAscending = true;

   List<TransactionAcrossMonthsItem> _data = [
    TransactionAcrossMonthsItem(
        'eDirham', 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1000, 70),
    TransactionAcrossMonthsItem(
        'tasheel', 120, 120, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 2000, 20),
    TransactionAcrossMonthsItem(
        'immgration', 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 3000, 10)
  ];
  var _dataSource = TransactionsAcrossDataSource(_data);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: .....
      body: createReport(),
    );
  }



  Widget createReport() {
    return ListView(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0), children: <Widget>[
      PaginatedDataTable(
        header: Text('Year of ${widget.yearOf}'),
        rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
        onRowsPerPageChanged: (int value) {
          setState(() {
            _rowsPerPage = value;
          });
        },
        sortColumnIndex: _sortColumnIndex,
        sortAscending: _sortAscending,
        // onSelectAll: _dataSource._selectAll,
        columns: getColumns(),
        source: _dataSource,
      )
    ]);
  }

  List<DataColumn> getColumns() {
    return [
      DataColumn(
        label: Text('Name'),
        ......
      ),
      DataColumn(
        .....
      ),
      ......
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed.

Comment: added the code used

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

What line causes the error you mention in your question?

Comment: var _dataSource = TransactionsAcrossDataSource(_data);

Comment: You can't have random code outside of methods or constructors in a class. Change `var _dataSource = TransactionsAcrossDataSource(_data);` to `TransactionsAcrossDataSource _dataSource;` and move `_dataSource = TransactionsAcrossDataSource(_data);` to a constructor.

Comment: just to give u a glance how everything there is 3 classes on model ,second is the  inherited from DataTableSource which have no data yet and will receive it on constructor, the third is the widget that should supply the data to that class .. when trying to init the inherited with the data it throughs that error

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks a lot worked like a charm :)

Comment: You can answer your own question with how you could make it work. Then accept it to show that the question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 var _dataSource = TransactionsAcrossDataSource(_data);
```

to

```
TransactionsAcrossDataSource _dataSource;
```

and move

```
_dataSource = TransactionsAcrossDataSource(_data);
```

to a constructor.

as you can't have random code outside of methods or constructors in a class.